# How to cast Guava's "Sets.combinations" returns back to usable Object Type?

Tags: java, casting, guava

Basically, i get all unique 10-combinations of my heroes with Guavas Sets.combinations method. 
My Input is a list of hero instances/objects. The output in my Set seems to be 
java.lang.Object or the Guava.Sets extending javas Object.

How do i cast these Object subsets to arrays or lists containing my hero objects again?

```
private void createHeroCombinations(){
        Set combinations = Sets.combinations(ImmutableSet.copyOf(heroList),10);
        this.combinationList = combinations;

        System.out.println(combinations.size());

        Iterator iterator = this.combinationList.iterator();

        System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
        System.out.println(iterator.next().getClass());
        Hero[] heroArray = (Hero[]) iterator.next();
    }
```

Output of soutp:

```
2147483647
[Hero@4617c264, Hero@5ca881b5, Hero@24d46ca6, Hero@4517d9a3, Hero@372f7a8d, Hero@5305068a, Hero@1f32e575, Hero@279f2327, Hero@2ff4acd0, Hero@54bedef2]
class com.google.common.collect.Sets$5$1$1
```

Casting error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Sets$5$1$1 cannot be cast to [LHero;
    at MetaCalculator.createHeroCombinations(MetaCalculator.java:208)
    at MetaCalculator.<init>(MetaCalculator.java:36)
    at MetaCalculator.main(MetaCalculator.java:14)
```

All i can do is take it as an java.lang.object:

```
Object o = iterator.next();
```

But where do i go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a set of set from the combination method. So use the appropriate generics:

```
Set<Set<Hero>> combos = Sets.combination(ImmutableSet.copyOf(heroes),10);
```

And then use the following iterator :

```
Iterator<Set<Hero>> comboIterator = combos.iterator();
Set<Hero> comboOne = comboIterator.next();
for(Hero hero:comboOne) {
  // Do something with hero
}
```

Note that despite the `[...]` notation, you don't get an array (`Hero[]`), but a `Collection<Hero>` (a `Set<Hero>`, actually)!